# using [self setVariable:value] vs variable = value

Tags: objective-c

In Objective C what scenario would I want to use `[self setVariable:value];` instead of `variable = value;`

It seems as if doing a self set I'm saving myself few lines of code, but what other advantages are there? Additionally, when would I NOT want to do a self set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:
I should clarify, that what I am referencing below is strictly in regards to variables that are properties.  If a variable is just an ivar, then there is no difference between `self.variable = value` or `variable = value`, other than the fact that `self.variable = value` will not even compile if it is just an ivar, in that case you need to use `self->variable = value`

Calling

```
[self setVariable:value];
```

is the same as calling

```
self.variable = value;
```

This, however, is **NOT** the same as

```
variable = value;
```

The first two cases use the synthesized `setVariable` method (or the one you defined yourself).  The reason you would want to use this is to make sure you keep the proper retain count on your objects.

For example, a simple property such as:

```
@property (retain) NSString *myString;
```

Gets an automatically generated set function that looks something like:

```
-(void) setMyString:(NSString*)other
{
    myString = [other retain];
}
```

If you were to just call

```
myString = otherString;
```

elsewhere in your code, then `myString` is not retained properly, so if `otherString` gets deallocated, your pointer to that object is no longer valid.

Comment: Your first statement is actually not true.  It very much depends on how the setVariable method is written.  A self.variable = value; will perform absolutely no validation, where a routine COULD be built to validate all inputs.

Comment: My understanding was that `self.variable = value;` automatically invoked the underlying `setVariable` method

Comment: How would the compiler know to do this on a custom object with custom variables that, lets say are int versus lets say an NSInteger?  If you specifically took an NSString and "retain"ed it, then later you simply did a string = nil;  Would that actually deallocate it or would that be a leak?  I beleive it would be a leak, which is proof that it cant be calling a setter routine, as if it did, and GOOD code would recognize the input as nil and deallocate before setting!!!

Comment: I think I see your point, if you synthesize the variable your point about the automatic method call is correct.  In the past I have not been using synthesized variables.  Good answer :-)  +1

Comment: It knows to do that because that is how properties work.  You'll note that you cannot access non-property variables using the `.` operator in objective-C since everything is a pointer.  That is to say, that `self.variable = value` is NOT the same as `self->variable = value`

Comment: Yes, Yes.  I took a much deeper look at your answer, and you are absolutely correct for using properties :-)  I upped your answer for that reason.  I was thinking back to all of my code where I am NOT using properties.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of using setter over assigning value to variable is to achieve Encapsulation.

Some Benefits are -

1. Encapsulation with getting or setting the property allows additional functionality (like validation) to be added more easily later.
2. Hiding the instance variable.
3. Effective memory management.

Comment: your number 2 doesnt make any difference for an object looking at it's own instance variables, they wont be hidden.  Good overall answer :-)  +1

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use it when holding objects that require retaining and releasing in order to conform to the Objective-C memory management model. For example:

MyObject.h:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *_name;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *name;

@end
```

MyObject.m:

```
@implementation MyObject

@synthesize name = _name;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name:%d", 12];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.name = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

For data types like `int`, `float`, etc., that don't require memory management you can get away without using the setter/getter methods, however it's good practice to use them all the time.